# A (rather) specific design for a custom persistent tree-like data structure

Tags: java, mysql, database, data-structures, persistence

First of all, design: I need some kind of tree, where each node can have arbitrary number of children. Each node carries a payload. The total payload of the node is the payload of the specific node + payloads of all it's ancestors till the root node.

Operations expected to be performed on the tree are: insertion, updating, deletion (rather frequently), merging subtrees into the tree (less frequently). There is also an operation of changing the subtree's position in the tree, with consequent recomputing of the payloads of the node AND all of its descendants.

The concrete implementation could be anything from just a plain persistent map to the specifically designed MySQL schema (NoSQL solutions are taken into consideration too). Preferred language (or existence of bindings) is Java, but if you could just give me an advise about the proper data structure, that'll be good, too.

The question is - what is the most proper solution in my case?

Comment: Sorry, the question is?

Comment: @Taylor, what's the weather like today?, of course

Comment: Trees in sql, you have a couple of options.  One is the one-to-many node-to-node relationship.  This works in some instances, but you don't know the depth of a given node, and need to climb the tree recursively which sql sucks at.  The other approach is nested sets.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 0):

Relational Databases are not well suited for hierarchical data. They can do it, but queries to do anything but the most basic things tend to be horribly complicated.

As for a NoSQL, I can recommend [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)  - it is a persistent datastore written in Java for Java, and especially designed for hierarchical data. It supports transactions, security, and XPath style and SQL style queries.